# Amazon e2 free tier 503 error

Tags: amazon-ec2, parse-server

I am using the amazon aws e2 to host a parse server database. It was working fine for the last couple of weeks, but today I got an error 503 saying: `The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.` My question is: is it because I'm using the free  t2.micro tier and I have run out of quota? Or can there be some other problem? I just launched another instance and it seems to be working fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up a load balancer? Checkout Elastic Beanstalk, which manages EC2 instances to automatically spin servers up and down as your needs require it. Your server may have just crashed and nothign was set up to automatically redeploy it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I set up the load balancer for my instance it will automatically restart my instance?

Comment: Yup, and it enables you to easily set config variables on the EB environment. Did you use the AWS tool for setting up parse-server? It should create an EB instance for you instead of EC2. If you just went straight EC2, you may have set something up where it requires you to SSH into the instance and initialize the server stuff yourself, which is bad for production.

Comment: No I have launched the instance straight from the aws console. Can I still create the load balancer from the console and connect it to my instance?

Comment: Mkight be more difficult to do.  I suggest you use the AWS Parse deploy tool here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Follow the guide and then move your own cloud code into the necessary folders.

Comment: And it will also create the balance loader for me in the process right?

Comment: Yup, it creates an Elastic Beanstalk instance already configured to spin up some EC2 instances for you. There is some additional set up you can do to make it even more production ready. Increase sizes, max number of instances, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144007/discussion-between-samatovs-and-jake-t).